# Can I travel alone on a UK Child Visit visa?

Tags: visas, uk, children

I am 16 years old. I have got UK visit accompanied with my parents only. Now I have to travel alone to UK next week. Can I go with the same visa? Kindly advice me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am a minor with a UK Accompanied visa. Will I be allowed to travel without my parent?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64525/i-am-a-minor-with-a-uk-accompanied-visa-will-i-be-allowed-to-travel-without-my)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. This question is about somebody who wants to arrive with the adult named on their visa, but leave without them. The other question is about somebody who wants to arrive without the named adult, because the adult is already in the UK.

Comment: @DavidRicherby it is a duplicate, please re-read both questions, as well as the answers: in both cases a minor wants to use an accompanied visa to travel *alone*.

Comment: @JonathanReez [A friendly reminder that duplicates should be the same question, not different questions with similar answers](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/3638/11491).

Comment: @DavidRicherby can you please point out the exact difference between the questions? This Q says "Now I have to travel alone to UK next week", the other Q says "Will I be allowed in the airport to enter if my parent (that I'm accompanied by) is already in the UK ". Same exact situation - only difference is possibly the location of OP's parents within the UK, which doesn't matter.

Comment: @JonathanReez The difference is precisely that, in one question, the parents are in the UK and, in the other, they're not. Those are, conceivably, very different situations: travelling to meet one's parents, versus travelling completely alone. The answers say that they're not actually different situations but this is exactly the point the meta post I linked you to is making: they are different questions that happen to have the same answer. The consensus of opinion on this site is that they are, therefore, not duplicates of each other.

Comment: @DavidRicherby ok, makes sense. Close vote retracted

Comment: @JonathanReez Thanks! (It does seem that I got confused between this question and one of the other related ones in my first comment; but I do think the question here and the proposed duplicate are distinct.)

Answer (score 3):

[Form the UK gov website](https://www.gov.uk/child-visit-visa/travelling-alone)

> 7. Travelling alone

You can travel to the UK without an adult (someone over the age of 18).

Your parent or guardian will need to provide their:

- written consent for you to travel to the UK
- full contact details

They’ll also need to provide proof that you have somewhere suitable to live during your stay in the UK, including:

- the name and date of birth of the person that you will be staying with
- an address where you will be living
- details of your relationship to the person who’ll be looking after you
- consent in writing so they can look after you during your stay in the UK

You must provide a letter from the school confirming it has notified the local authority of your visit and your care arrangements if:

- you’ll be studying in the UK during your stay
- you’re under 16

You must include the reply from the local authority if the school has received one.

> I can go same visa?

As @GayotFlow mentions, the issuing post will write the conditions on the entry clearance itself. If the conditions stipulate that an adult is required, then they cannot travel alone. Otherwise it's ok. In both cases, it's an EXPLICIT amendment made by the consulate.

Comment: +1, for your part about 'No clarification...'.  The issuing post will write the conditions on the entry clearance itself.  If the conditions stipulate that an adult is required, then they cannot travel alone.  Otherwise it's ok.  In both cases, it's an EXPLICIT amendment made by the consulate.  Please edit.

Answer (score 0):

You will need more than a visa to travel at 16 years of age.

If traveling by yourself, you will need signed and notarized letters from both parents authorizing you to travel.  Without knowing your nationality, there is a good chance you will need these documents to be allowed to exit your home country, so might need them in both your home language and English.

Your current visa if restricted to traveling with your parents would be of no use.  Your best source of information is to contact the UK Embassy or Consulate that issued your visa.