# Travelling to The UK alone with a child accompanied visa

Tags: customs-and-immigration, children

i was going to travel to the UK alone and i recently just got my visa however i didnt realise that the name of my father would be mentioned on my visa stating that my visa is only valid if i am accompanied by him, however on the UK government site it is stated that if a child comes to the UK alone and without the person mentioned on their visa then they should present a consent letter and accomodation proof, if i take these 2 things with me and travel there will it still be a problem for entry and should i take this risk or not, thanks

Comment: I think OP is referring to the last paragraph on [this UK government page](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor/if-youre-under-18): If you arrive in the UK without the person named in your visa, you’ll need to show that your parent or guardian consents to your travel and accommodation arrangements.

Comment: I think the problem is that the visa clearly states that "only valid if accompanied by X or Y".

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74169/can-i-go-to-uk-holding-an-accompanied-visa-unaccompanied

Comment: If you’re flying to the UK, the airline might might deny boarding