# Can I change my visa status from accompanied to unaccompanied

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, minors, transition-of-visa-status, denied-boarding

I am a student in another country while my family stays in Nigeria. We all planned a vacation to London. My siblings and mum got their passports out first and they left. I got mine later and I have been refused to board the plane because it clearly states that my mum has to accompany me.

Is there a way I can change my visa status from accompanied to unaccompanied, or can it be authorized that I can come in with someone else?

Answer (score 5):

This page https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor/if-youre-under-18 implies that you can arrive in the UK without the person named in your visa *if* you can show that your parent or guardian consents to your travel and accommodation arrangements.

However, in practice you’d need to convince an airline to allow you to board. Airlines are on the hook for anyone they transport who is refused entry on arrival at the destination, so they may very well refuse you boarding unless they could somehow verify the validity of the authorisation, which seems unlikely. So you will in all probability need a new visa.

See also [I am a minor with a UK Accompanied visa. Will I be allowed to travel without my parent, who is already in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64525/i-am-a-minor-with-a-uk-accompanied-visa-will-i-be-allowed-to-travel-without-my)